# read textbox input per line and do a for loop in php to curl

Tags: php

I do have an html form that accepts textbox input of sha1 hashes per line:

```
    <textarea id="mid "name="mid" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Example values are:

```
    9a3845cf0aac825d4e754610baa473f53636f10a
    9a3845cf0aac825d4e754610baa473f53636f10b
    9a3845cf0aac825d4e754610baa473f53636f10c
```

My problem is I need to take each value from the textbox "per line" and pass it to curl, my code below works only on a single entry basis:

```
    <?php
    $pf="pf";
    $ur="ur";
    $pw="pw";
    $url="url.com";
    extract($_POST);
    $mid=$_POST['mid'];

    $fields = array(
        'user'=>urlencode($ur),
        'pass'=>urlencode($pw),
        'pfid'=>urlencode($pf),
        'msid'=>urlencode($mid)
    );

    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string,'&');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

My expected output from the curl'ed server are the results of all those from the textbox:

```
    9a3845cf0aac825d4e754610baa473f53636f10a - okay
    9a3845cf0aac825d4e754610baa473f53636f10b - cancelled
    9a3845cf0aac825d4e754610baa473f53636f10c - okay
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`explode` on the new line character:

```
$mids = explode("\n", $mid);
```

Then you can access each line:

```
foreach ($mids as $mid){
    // ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. It worked. This is what I did from the actual code:

```
<?php
$pf="pf";
$ur="ur";
$pw="pw";
$url="url.com";
extract($_POST);
$mid=$_POST['mid'];
$mids = explode("\n", $mid);

foreach ($mids as $mid){

$fields = array(
    'user'=>urlencode($ur),
    'pass'=>urlencode($pw),
    'pfid'=>urlencode($pf),
    'msid'=>urlencode($mid)
);

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

}
?>
```

I now have an output. My only issue is that pre-formatting it. I am actually expecting an output of four (4) fields and lines = x. Curently I'm getting the output as:

```
ID: 947c5d5982bf1a83020bca6c330fe94f
  Stat: OKID: c9218019acde8ff547779c4ecd77f8f4
  Stat: OKID: 47f2c7d65a9c3cccda3a9eb7497dbeee Stat: OK
```

Instead of the correct one

```
ID: 947c5d5982bf1a83020bca6c330fe94f Stat: OK
ID: c9218019acde8ff547779c4ecd77f8f4 Stat: OK
ID: 47f2c7d65a9c3cccda3a9eb7497dbeee Stat: OK
```

Is there a sample for this? Should I use explode to fix the formatting. Thanks again.